# Button clicks check boxes based on if statement results

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a teeny bit of help with some code. What this is supposed to do, is find out what button the user is clicking, and then change check boxes based on which button the user presses. But I don't know what to put in the `var enabled = button.Name ==;` line to pull from the if statements.

```
        private void EnDis(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var enabled = button.Name == ; //confusing
        var disabled = button.Name == ; //confusing
        if(button.Name == "btnEnable_1")
        {
            chk_1.IsChecked = enabled;
            chk_2.IsChecked = enabled;
            chk_3.IsChecked = enabled;
            chk_4.IsChecked = enabled;
        }
            if(button.Name == "btnDisable_1")
        {
            chk_1.IsChecked = disabled;
            chk_2.IsChecked = disabled;
            chk_3.IsChecked = disabled;
            chk_4.IsChecked = disabled;
        }

        if(button.Name == "btnEnable_2")
        {
            chk_5.IsChecked = enabled;
            chk_6.IsChecked = enabled;
            chk_7.IsChecked = enabled;
            chk_8.IsChecked = enabled;
        }

    }
```

Any help or guidance will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this you want?

```
   private void EnDis(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    if(button.Name == "btnEnable_1")
    {
        chk_1.IsChecked = true;
        chk_2.IsChecked = true;
        chk_3.IsChecked = true;
        chk_4.IsChecked = true;
    }
        if(button.Name == "btnDisable_1")
    {
        chk_1.IsChecked = false;
        chk_2.IsChecked = false;
        chk_3.IsChecked = false;
        chk_4.IsChecked = false;
    }

    if(button.Name == "btnEnable_2")
    {
        chk_5.IsChecked = true;
        chk_6.IsChecked = true;
        chk_7.IsChecked = true;
        chk_8.IsChecked = true;
    }

}
```